# mapping to multiple tables and adding validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to convert an existing data layer to EF as a proof of concept for my company to start a new project with it. I ran across an issue with the one class because it's mapped to two tables. I'm also trying to use the Fluent API to do what validation I can there to keep things cleaner.

I did a couple of searches for answers here, and couldn't find anything.

This is my configuration file that I have so far. Any insight on better ways to do things would also be appreciated.

```
internal class StoreConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Store>{
        public StoreConfiguration() {
            Map(m => {
                m.ToTable("tblStore");
                m.HasKey(s => s.ID);
                m.Property(s => s.ID).HasColumnName("strID");
                m.Property(s => s.SiteID).HasColumnName("strSiteID");
                m.Property(s => s.StoreStatusID).HasColumnName("strStatusID");
                m.Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("strNumber").IsRequired();
                m.Property(s => s.Caption).HasColumnName("strCaption").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(80);
                m.Property(s => s.Notes).HasColumnName("strNotes");
                m.Property(s => s.LandlordName).HasColumnName("strLandlordName").HasMaxLength(80);
                m.Property(s => s.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("strIsDeleted");
                m.Property(s => s.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("strCreatedBy").HasMaxLength(64);
                m.Property(s => s.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("strCreatedOn");
                m.Property(s => s.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("strModifiedBy").HasMaxLength(64);
                m.Property(s => s.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("strModifiedOn");
                m.Property(s => s.DeletedBy).HasColumnName("strDeletedBy").HasMaxLength(64);
                m.Property(s => s.DeletedOn).HasColumnName("strDeletedOn");
            }).Map(m => {
                m.ToTable("tblIPLocation");
                m.Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("LD_STORE#");
                m.Property(s => s.District).HasColumnName("LD_DIST#");
                m.Property(s => s.DMName).HasColumnName("LD_DMGR");
                m.Property(s => s.Region).HasColumnName("LD_REG#");
                m.Property(s => s.RMName).HasColumnName("LD_RMGR");
            });
        }
    }
```

Right now, I'm getting errors on all of the `.IsRequired()`, `.HasMaxLength()`, and `.HasKey()` as they are not properties of the lambda object. When I wasn't using `m.` for all of those Properties, ToTable, and HasKey, it was working fine. Am I just missing a cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this was done in "bad practice" from the beginning. The details in the second table was data that was provided by another system outside of our control, so in all honesty, it should be a separate class.

I did find [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/23/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) which describes two ways to accomplish this. Since the IDs do not match, the only option would be to use a View. However, since I'm only building a Proof-of-Concept, I'll just create a separate class for this.

If there are other ways to do this in the newer versions of Entity Framework, please let me know. I just didn't want to leave this question unanswered in case other people stumble across it.